# Unable to drag and drop or edit toolbox elements in Visual Studio Community Edition 2022 for ASP.NET Web Forms (C#) in Designer View

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, webforms, design-view

I have followed the approximate steps of this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o0GNwALxgQ8) in an attempt to create an ASP.NET Web Form.

Inside the video, the programmer was able to directly edit text within the designer view, as well as right click to edit elements.

However, while trying to recreate these steps in Visual Studio Community Edition 2022, I am unable to do so, only being able to manually type in the html file. The following image is the designer view for a newly created blank web form component:
[image: design view for new web form component]

Has the old method of drag and drop been deprecated, or have I missed a crucial step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I was able to solve the issue by going to Tools > Options > Web Forms Designer, select the "Legacy Web Forms Designer" Options, and restart Visual Studio

[image]

[image]

Comment: do keep in the new "live" preview options  - they do allow editing even in your browser. I not played with the new setup, but nice to see some great new options for web forms now. It not clear why the drag + drop goes away when you use the live preview, but it is supposed to be rather nice, and still allow drag + drop. Just not yet time to try and play with this new feature for web forms in vs2022.